# Real-time Image Recognition app using WCF and Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf, windows-phone-7, image-recognition

Is it possible (if so, effective) to do a Real-time Image Recognition app using WCF and Silverlight?. This app is supposed to be implemented on Windows Phone 7 platform. As the processing can't be done inside WP7 itself I'm hoping to stream-out the video feed using web services...

Correct me if I'm having any mis-understanding...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at http://visualfindr.codeplex.com/

It is a WP7 wrapper to an image recognition service. It requires an image to be selected/passed or photo to be taken to work with as third party access to the camera stream is not currently available on Window Phone 7.

Answer (score 1):

Not currently possible sorry, you can't access the camera directly. You can only start a new "task" to capture an image or video - The OS takes over for the duration of the task and will return the result to your application.

So yes you can do image capture/recognition (As you've already stated it would be highly recommended to offload this to a server) but no it can't be done in real time.